# Will missed shebang stop the script for running

Tags: cron

I have a crontab job to purge the logs from /var/log/nginx folder. The crontab was set up like this:

```
15 23 * * * /scripts/logcleanup.sh > /dev/null 2>&1
```

The logcleanup.sh script is very simple, it only has two line:

```
find /var/log/nginx -mtime +5 -type f -delete;
find /var/log/nginx -size +50M -type f -delete;
```

I supposed the script will be run every night at 23:15. However, it doesn't get executed and the files larger than 50 MB are still inside the log folder. Is this caused by the missing Shebang "`#!/usr/bin/env bash`" ?

Thanks.

Comment: There's not enough information to tell. Why is the shebang missing? Why don't you just add it? (And why `#!/usr/bin/env bash` rather than `#!/bin/bash`?) Finally, is `logcleanup.sh` executable?

Answer (score 0):

Redirect the output to a log file instead of `/dev/null` to get feedback:

```
15 23 * * * /scripts/logcleanup.sh > ~/logcleanup.sh.log 2>&1
```

All the errors will be logged and hopefully, you will find out what is wrong.